# Запятая перед "как в"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

**Автор поддерживает слова Ибн Араби, что в исламе нет духовенства(,) как в христианстве, и поэтому...**
Нужна ли запятая в скобках?
(Вопрос простой, но, хоть и стыдно, не знаю ответа.)

Comment: Сначала надо прояснить для себя вопрос: есть ли в христианстве духовенство.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Автор поддерживает слова Ибн Араби ( о том), что **в исламе** нет духовенства, **как в христианстве,** и поэтому..

**Обычный сравнительный оборот** (**в исламе, как в христианстве**; названы оба предмета, которые сравниваются), нет причин, чтобы не ставить запятую.

**А вот перестраивать предложение для объяснения знаков препинания строго нежелательно**, так как это будет другое предложение. Это неправильный, хотя и распространенный метод, который в последнее время стал использоваться на форуме.

Надо помнить, что одно и то же содержание можно представить в виде различных синтаксических форм (так называемая **синтаксическая синонимия**), и для каждого случая будут действовать свои правила.

Comment: *вот перестраивать предложение для объяснения знаков препинания строго нежелательно* — предложение обычно перестраивается не для объяснения знаков препинания, а для чёткого разграничения интерпретаций, которые, между прочим, зависят от расстановки знаков. В противном случае можно ошибиться, вложив в текст не тот смысл, который вкладывает автор вопроса (это, кстати, на форуме встречается намного чаще).

Comment: Мы можем перестраивать предложение, чтобы лучше понять его смысл, но потом мы должны вернуться к той  форме, которую выбрал автор и работать с ней. Нужно определить грамматику авторского варианта, применить нужное правило, но в любом случае не копировать знаки препинания из одного предложения в другое.

Answer (score 0):

Да, запятая поистине необходима. При [отсутствии](https://best-language.ru/zapjataja-pered-kak-ne-stavitsja) запятой предложение получает такой смысл:

*"Автор поддерживает слова Ибн-Араби, что ислам подобен христианству тем, что в нём нет духовенства".*

При [наличии](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183) получается смысл:

**"Автор поддерживает слова Ибн-Араби, что в христианстве нет подобного исламскому духовенства".**

Полагаю, что даже при минимальном понимании очевидно, какое из утверждений является истинным.

Comment: *что в христианстве нет подобного исламскому  духовенства* — В тексте утверждается обратное.

Comment: @grizzly а что утверждается в тексте?

Comment: @Aer Во-первых, я считаю, что при отсутствии запятой предложению нельзя придать смысл. Таким образом, запятая в любом случае необходима (я объяснял в удалённых ответах, что именно за это ставлю минус). Утверждается, по-моему, что духовенство в исламе не такое, как в христианстве (хотя предложение не вполне точно, и если ничего не знать о религиях, его сложно понять правильно). Из такого утверждения не следует обратное. (Ср.: у Маши нет такого мячика, как у Пети. Это не значит (грамматичкски), что у Пети нет такого, как у Маши.)

Comment: @grizzly : не путайте "смысл" и "истинность высказывания".

Comment: Конечно. Я не путаю. Посмотрите мой пример про Петю и Машу. Меня не интересует, какие у них на самом деле мячики, я определяю смысл исходя из понимания имеющегося текста.

Comment: Смысл именно такой: В ИСЛАМЕ вообще НЕТ  духовенства, а в христианстве ЕСТЬ (какое - это др. вопрос).  Главное, я понял, что зпт нужна. Спасибо!

Comment: @Рад Позвольте, а можно весь текст статьи? Потому что ну не может быть такого, оно есть, просто отличается от того, что в христианстве.

Comment: @grizzly Тут речь о семантике (логике), и запятые определяются именно на основании семантики. Иначе Вы пытаетесь отделить грамматическое значение от логического, что н.е.в.м.е.с.т.н.о. :-)

Comment: @Рад В исламе есть духовенство, если мы одинаково понимаем, что такое [духовенство](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE&all=x). Если где-то говорят, что в исламе нет духовенства, то имеют в виду как раз то, что оно [отличается](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) от духовенства в христианстве.

Comment: @Manjusri Согласен с последним Вашим замечанием, за исключением того, что оно якобы может оправдывать ошибочное понимание семантики и грамматики.

Comment: Во-первых, в предложении не обсуждается НАЛИЧИЕ духовенства, а говорится, что "Автор поддерживает слова Ибн Араби, что...", во-вторых, в исламе ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО нет духовенства (непонятки из-за того, что многие не правильно понимают это слово). Для таких ВИКИ: Исла́мское духове́нство — УСЛОВНЫЙ термин, «поскольку в исламе не существует институтов духовенства, аналогичных христианской церкви как в функциональном, так и в структурном отношении».[1]

«Под мусульманским духовенством подразумевают совокупность лиц, связанных с отправлением культа (мулла, муэдзин), судей (кади), правоведов...

Comment: @Рад Ну и в чём проблема? Из вики тоже следует, что духовенство (пусть даже в "условном" смысле) - есть. Вики говорит то же самое, что и я: духовенство - есть, просто не такое, как в христианстве.